Weird error that appears only with the scheduled trigger
Everything works well when I'm launching the script manually. But when the script is executed with the daily scheduled trigger; it fails. It fails at the stage when an array is sorted.
2024-04-24 05:47:58 Central European Summer Time    mettreenforme   TypeError: a[0].getTime is not a function   time-based  2024-04-24 05:48:09 Central European Summer Time
The code is the following one :
tableautampon.sort(function(a,b){
      if (a[0].getTime()===b[0].getTime()){
         return (a[1].localeCompare(b[1]))
      } else if(a[0]>b[0]){
         return 1;
      } else if(a[0]<b[0]){
         return -1;
      }
   })

tableautampon is an 2D Array. The first element of each raw is a date. For example, the first row is :
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{BE}',
'UCB BB',
1.36,
'sek',
'Regular Cash' ]
I've tried to execute
console.log(tableautampon[0].getTime()

I've got TypeError: tableautampon[0].getTime is not a function
I've also tried to put that to get only the first elements of each row, not working
if (a[0][0].getTime()===b[0][0].getTime()){

I'm quite lost why it seems to work manually and not with a trigger (and why when I'm trying to select only the first element of a 2D array with sort function, it's not working)
NB : tableau tampon is
[ [ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{BE}',
'UCB BB',
1.36,
'sek',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{FI}',
'HUH1V FH',
0.53,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{FI}',
'SAMPO FH',
0.2,
'€',
'Special Cash' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{FI}',
'SAMPO FH',
1.6,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{FR}',
'OR FP',
6.6,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{GE}',
'BAS GY',
3.4,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{GE}',
'MUV2 GY',
15,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{NE}',
'ABN NA',
0.89,
'€',
'Final' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{NE}',
'ASML NA',
1.75,
'€',
'Final' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{NO}',
'TOM NO',
1.95,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SW}',
'ALFA SS',
7.5,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SW}',
'WALLB SS',
0.25,
'chf',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SZ}',
'BANB SE',
0.4,
'€',
'Return of Capital' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SZ}',
'BANB SE',
0.4,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SZ}',
'CMBN SE',
4,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SZ}',
'SIGN SE',
0.48,
'sek',
'Return of Capital' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{BE}',
'UMI BB',
0.55,
'€',
'Final' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{GE}',
'BAYN GY',
0.11,
'sek',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{GE}',
'CON GY',
2.2,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{GE}',
'MRK GY',
2.2,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{NE}',
'AKZA NA',
1.54,
'chf',
'Final' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{NE}',
'BESI NA',
2.15,
'chf',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{NE}',
'HEIA NA',
1.04,
'€',
'Final' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{NE}',
'HEIO NA',
1.04,
'chf',
'Final' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SP}',
'ITX SQ',
0.77,
'chf',
'Interim' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SP}',
'SAN SQ',
0.07695,
'chf',
'Final' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SW}',
'EVO SS',
2.65,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SW}',
'HPOLB SS',
2,
'€',
'Special Cash' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SW}',
'HPOLB SS',
4,
'chf',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SW}',
'THULE SS',
4.75,
'chf',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SZ}',
'BCVN SE',
4.3,
'sek',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{DE}',
'MAERSKB DC',
2,
'€',
'Spinoff' ],
[ Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{FR}',
'CS FP',
1.98,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{FR}',
'EN FP',
1.9,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{FR}',
'VIV FP',
0.25,
'sek',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{NO}',
'DNB NO',
16,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SW}',
'HEXAB SS',
0.13,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SW}',
'SAND SS',
5.5,
'sek',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SW}',
'SAVE SS',
7.2,
'$',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SZ}',
'BALN SE',
7.7,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SZ}',
'UBSG SE',
0.35,
'$',
'Return of Capital' ],
[ Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{SZ}',
'UBSG SE',
0.35,
'€',
'Regular Cash' ],
[ Wed May 01 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{DE}',
'RBREW DC',
'',
'€',
'Omitted' ],
[ Wed May 01 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{DE}',
'RBREW DC',
14.5,
'€',
'Special Cash' ],
[ Thu May 02 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
'{FR}',
'ENGI FP',
1.43,
'€',
'Final' ],

Try this:
function myfunk31() {
  const arr = [[ "Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{BE}', 'UCB BB', 1.36, 'sek', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{FI}', 'HUH1V FH', 0.53, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{FI}', 'SAMPO FH', 0.2, '€', 'Special Cash' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{FI}', 'SAMPO FH', 1.6, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{FR}', 'OR FP', 6.6, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{GE}', 'BAS GY', 3.4, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{GE}', 'MUV2 GY', 15, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{NE}', 'ABN NA', 0.89, '€', 'Final' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{NE}', 'ASML NA', 1.75, '€', 'Final' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{NO}', 'TOM NO', 1.95, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SW}', 'ALFA SS', 7.5, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SW}', 'WALLB SS', 0.25, 'chf', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SZ}', 'BANB SE', 0.4, '€', 'Return of Capital' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SZ}', 'BANB SE', 0.4, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SZ}', 'CMBN SE', 4, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SZ}', 'SIGN SE', 0.48, 'sek', 'Return of Capital' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{BE}', 'UMI BB', 0.55, '€', 'Final' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{GE}', 'BAYN GY', 0.11, 'sek', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{GE}', 'CON GY', 2.2, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{GE}', 'MRK GY', 2.2, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{NE}', 'AKZA NA', 1.54, 'chf', 'Final' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{NE}', 'BESI NA', 2.15, 'chf', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{NE}', 'HEIA NA', 1.04, '€', 'Final' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{NE}', 'HEIO NA', 1.04, 'chf', 'Final' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SP}', 'ITX SQ', 0.77, 'chf', 'Interim' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SP}', 'SAN SQ', 0.07695, 'chf', 'Final' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SW}', 'EVO SS', 2.65, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SW}', 'HPOLB SS', 2, '€', 'Special Cash' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SW}', 'HPOLB SS', 4, 'chf', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SW}', 'THULE SS', 4.75, 'chf', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SZ}', 'BCVN SE', 4.3, 'sek', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{DE}', 'MAERSKB DC', 2, '€', 'Spinoff' ], ["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{FR}', 'CS FP', 1.98, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{FR}', 'EN FP', 1.9, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{FR}', 'VIV FP', 0.25, 'sek', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{NO}', 'DNB NO', 16, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SW}', 'HEXAB SS', 0.13, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SW}', 'SAND SS', 5.5, 'sek', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SW}', 'SAVE SS', 7.2, '$', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SZ}', 'BALN SE', 7.7, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SZ}', 'UBSG SE', 0.35, '$', 'Return of Capital' ], ["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{SZ}', 'UBSG SE', 0.35, '€', 'Regular Cash' ], ["Wed May 01 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{DE}', 'RBREW DC', '', '€', 'Omitted' ], ["Wed May 01 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{DE}', 'RBREW DC', 14.5, '€', 'Special Cash' ], ["Thu May 02 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)", '{FR}', 'ENGI FP', 1.43, '€', 'Final' ]];

  arr.sort(function(a,b){
      if (new Date(a[0]).getTime()=== new Date(b[0]).getTime()){
         return (a[1].localeCompare(b[1]))
      } else if(new Date(a[0]).valueOf()>new Date(b[0]).valueOf()){
         return 1;
      } else if(new Date(a[0]).valueOf()<new Date(b[0]).valueOf()){
         return -1;
      }
   })
   Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/],/g,'],\n'))
}

Execution log
9:30:25 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:30:23 AM  Info    [["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{BE}","UCB BB",1.36,"sek","Regular Cash"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{FI}","HUH1V FH",0.53,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{FI}","SAMPO FH",0.2,"€","Special Cash"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{FI}","SAMPO FH",1.6,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{FR}","OR FP",6.6,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{GE}","BAS GY",3.4,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{GE}","MUV2 GY",15,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{NE}","ABN NA",0.89,"€","Final"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{NE}","ASML NA",1.75,"€","Final"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{NO}","TOM NO",1.95,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SW}","ALFA SS",7.5,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SW}","WALLB SS",0.25,"chf","Regular Cash"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SZ}","BANB SE",0.4,"€","Return of Capital"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SZ}","BANB SE",0.4,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SZ}","CMBN SE",4,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Fri Apr 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SZ}","SIGN SE",0.48,"sek","Return of Capital"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{BE}","UMI BB",0.55,"€","Final"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{GE}","BAYN GY",0.11,"sek","Regular Cash"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{GE}","CON GY",2.2,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{GE}","MRK GY",2.2,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{NE}","AKZA NA",1.54,"chf","Final"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{NE}","BESI NA",2.15,"chf","Regular Cash"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{NE}","HEIA NA",1.04,"€","Final"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{NE}","HEIO NA",1.04,"chf","Final"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SP}","ITX SQ",0.77,"chf","Interim"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SP}","SAN SQ",0.07695,"chf","Final"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SW}","EVO SS",2.65,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SW}","HPOLB SS",2,"€","Special Cash"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SW}","HPOLB SS",4,"chf","Regular Cash"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SW}","THULE SS",4.75,"chf","Regular Cash"],
["Mon Apr 29 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SZ}","BCVN SE",4.3,"sek","Regular Cash"],
["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{DE}","MAERSKB DC",2,"€","Spinoff"],
["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{FR}","CS FP",1.98,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{FR}","EN FP",1.9,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{FR}","VIV FP",0.25,"sek","Regular Cash"],
["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{NO}","DNB NO",16,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SW}","HEXAB SS",0.13,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SW}","SAND SS",5.5,"sek","Regular Cash"],
["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SW}","SAVE SS",7.2,"$","Regular Cash"],
["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SZ}","BALN SE",7.7,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SZ}","UBSG SE",0.35,"$","Return of Capital"],
["Tue Apr 30 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{SZ}","UBSG SE",0.35,"€","Regular Cash"],
["Wed May 01 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{DE}","RBREW DC","","€","Omitted"],
["Wed May 01 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{DE}","RBREW DC",14.5,"€","Special Cash"],
["Thu May 02 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)","{FR}","ENGI FP",1.43,"€","Final"]]
9:30:27 AM  Notice  Execution completed
value: string | number | Date, , , hint

